# How to extract a unicode string from a string

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8, split

I've a string of the form `"text: u'\u0644'"`, how to extract in python the inner unicode string? (i.e. to have `u'\u0644'`)

When I use `split()` I got `"u'\\u0644'"` which is a simple string!

Comment: If this is JSON, use `json.loads` to decode it to Python data structures.

Comment: no it is not json, it is raw text

Comment: where did it come from? Likely there's an easier way to get the information out of it.

Comment: the text was crawled from facebook, wonder if this may help!

Comment: 1) Facebook has an API which will be easier than screen-scraping their HTML, and 2) the text you are getting from their HTML is likely valid JSON. I strongly suggest that you back up and reconsider how you are approaching this....

Comment: the extra `\\` is an escape, try printing it after splitting

Comment: @Arbi: u'xxx' looks like the python representation of a unicode string. Sure, you don't convert something to a string, that is not meant to be converted?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham just after splitting the \ is escaped

Comment: @Daniel i'm working on a sample crawled content that was given to me

Comment: @Arbi can you show a sample of the crawled content?

Comment: @NedBatchelder here is a sample of what I do have 
id: 10152075477696749_23025844
message: u'\u05d0\u05d9\u05da \u05d5\u05d5\u05e2\u05dc \u05d6\u05d0\u05b8\u05d2\u05df \u05d0\u05b7\u05dc\u05e2\u05de\u05e2\u05df \u05d5\u05d5\u05d0\u05e1 \u05d0\u05d9\u05e8 \u05d8\u05d0\u05b7\u05e7\u05e2 \u05d6\u05e2\u05e0\u05e2\u05df \u05e9\u05e2\u05d3 - \u05e8\u05d9\u05dc\u05d9\u05e1 \u05e4\u05bc\u05d0\u05b7\u05dc\u05e2\u05e8\u05d3 \u05d0\u05d9\u05e6\u05d8'
created_time: 2014-02-15T23:32:10+0000
like_count: 0

Comment: @Arbi: I'd like to help you untangle this, it seems clear to me that you are going about this the hard way. But this forum isn't right for us to have an actual discussion about it.  :(

Comment: @NedBatchelder here is what i'm working on https://github.com/dzlab/sentimentpy

Comment: You are reading this text from a data file.  That data file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dzlab/sentimentpy/master/data/6815841748_10152075477696749.txt) has a very strange ad-hoc format.  What produces that file?  You could create it in a way that is much more conducive to reading it. I'm still betting that JSON will be a good answer.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I agree but as I said the file was given to me to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely convert the literal string:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval

>>> s = "text: u'\u0644'"

>>> unicode_part = s.split(':')[-1].strip()
>>> unicode_part
"u'\\u0644'"

>>> unicode_string = literal_eval(unicode_part)
>>> unicode_string
u'\u0644'
>>> print unicode_string
ل
```

Comment: why not just split on whitespace?

Comment: You can, and originally I did that, but the string looks like it's some sort of key value pair where the key and value are delimited by `:`, hence using `:` for the split. If you could be certain that there was always a space, then you could split on the space, or even on `: ` if there was always one space and avoid the `.strip()` - but this way is probably more robust.